# Disallow routing to paths with unused last child at the framework level

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project and I have having an issue with a route like

1. https://example.com/home/about
2. https://example.com/home/about/nosuchpath

routing to the same controller.

I wanted the 2nd one to return a http 404 error.

Currently both are routing to the home controller and about action.

I have read through the following Microsoft [Guide for Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but did not find anything on disallowing child paths.

My current solution is a bit dirty by decorating the controller action with an attribute that checks for any excess route:

```
public class NoParamsValidatorAttribute : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public NoParamsValidatorAttribute()
    {
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (ValidateIfAnyParams(context))
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }
    }

    private bool ValidateIfAnyParams(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        return (context?.ActionArguments?.Any() ?? false) || ((context?.RouteData?.Values?.Count ?? 0) > 2) || (context?.HttpContext?.Request?.QueryString.HasValue ?? false);
    }
}
```

Overall, I am looking for a solution that can be applied as a whole without relying on individually decorating controller actions as I have multiple controller actions facing the same issue.

I have a controller with actions like this, and I want to affect the first one without affect subsequent ones with method parameters.

```
  // home/about/xxx should return httpstatus 404.
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult About()
  {
     return View();
  }
  
  // home/viewinfo/abc should not have an issue with this
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult ViewInfo(string info)
  {
     return View(info);
  }
```

And for my startup.cs, I am tempted to specify the endpoint explicitly, but it seems very menial intensive for hundreds of controller actions in multiple controllers.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
     // ...
     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
         {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     });
     // ...
}
```

Comment: Any route napping which is more specific should be mapped first followed by less specific and more general mapping. You should move mapping `name: "default",` at last. The route mapping follows `{Controller}/{action}` pattern so as long at the URL follows that pattern mvc will process the request. That's why you are not getting 404 error.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thank you, I agree that that default should be last. I was intending to find a solution that does not force me to explicitly map all paths for each and every controller action without a parameter/query string. I have removed the misleading route mapping that I think distracts from the qns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to achieve your requirement is register a global action filter as your NoParamsValidatorAttribute.

This global action filter will fired before the request goes to the actually action and it is registered at the configure service method. This is no need to set it for each controller and actions.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
public class NoParamsValidator : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public NoParamsValidator()
    {
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (ValidateIfAnyParams(context))
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }
    }

    private bool ValidateIfAnyParams(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        return (context?.ActionArguments?.Any() ?? false) || ((context?.RouteData?.Values?.Count ?? 0) > 2) || (context?.HttpContext?.Request?.QueryString.HasValue ?? false);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs ConfigureServices add below codes:

```
     services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(NoParamsValidator));
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand my question was not clear of the whole scope where I do not want other actions with parameters/query string affected. This is actually an answer than answers the original question as I gave. I will keep this code block in mind for if I want a wholesale scenario to apply.

Comment: Do you mean you want some NoParamsValidator controllers. You could try to create a base controller and override its OnActionExecutionAsync method. Then you could write new controller inherits from this bas controller to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Besides, if you feel my reply is right and has helped you. Please mark it as answer so that other folks who faces the same issue could find the answer more easily. Thank you.